# How to extract/read data from a (youtube) stream object?

Tags: python, youtube, stream, extract

Below is my code:

```
from pytube import YouTube
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r-uOLxNrNk8'
video = YouTube(url).streams.get_highest_resolution()
```

I am trying to get a youtube video using pytube, using which I am trying to extract the filesize.

The variable video is of type <class 'pytube.streams.Stream'>, and contains multiple attributes of the video. I want to understand, how to extract/read this data (filesize, resolution, etc).

Comment: Per the pytube documentation (https://pytube.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=pytube.metadata#youtube-object) the `youtube` object should have a metadata property.  Have you checked that property to see what information is available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer.

To extract `filesize`, we just need to do use `<stream>.filesize`:

```
from pytube import YouTube
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r-uOLxNrNk8'
video = YouTube(url).streams.get_highest_resolution()
print(video.filesize)
```